# Any hints on how to use notebook control in Mono

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

Can someone please point me out to a short example of how to add and remove a window to a Notebook control in Mono? I have already searched for any examples but was unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found out how to do this in Mono:

```
    Widget1 win1 = new Widget1();

    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    hbox.PackStart(new Label("Pane 1") );
    Button close = new Button("×"); // Set this up with an image or whatever.
    close.Relief = ReliefStyle.None;
    close.FocusOnClick = false;
    close.Clicked += delegate {
        hbox.Destroy();
        win1.Destroy();
    };

    hbox.PackStart(close);
    hbox.ShowAll();

    nbMain.AppendPage(win1, hbox);
    win1.Show();
```

The main trick is that child panes (`Widget1` in my case) **should** inherit from `Widget`, not from `Window`!

Answer (score 1):

Only thing I found meanwhile: http://docs.go-mono.com/index.aspx?link=T%3AGtk.Notebook